# nodejs adding mongo connection to global

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im adding the mongo connection at server start to my global obj to access to it from any file

```
// app.js
mClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
  global.mongo = db;
});
```

and using it like this

```
// store.js  
global.mongo.collection(thisColl, function(err, collection) {
  if (err) return self.emit("error", "collection not found");

  collection.find(query, select).toArray(function(err, stores) {
    if (err || !stores) return self.emit("error", "result not found");

    return self.emit("done", stores);
    });
  });
```

but sometimes im getting and error that get fixed alone, I dont know how

```
// Error
{"code":"InternalError","message":"Cannot call method 'collection' of undefined"}
```

Im doing this becouse it doesnt open/close a connection on every request

Comment: Is it possible the `global.mongo.collection` call is happening before the `mClientconnect` callback occurs?

Comment: actually global.mongo.collection gets call with an http call. but i think mClient.connect get called when a find is perform

Comment: the mongodb-node-native driver is full event driven, so use it event-driven way. otherwise it would totally mess up.

Comment: The "connect" should be happening when your app starts.  You should also be checking the "err" value for an error.  As "notXX" suggested your app should not start accepting requests until the "connect" callback fires, otherwise an a request can sneak in before the connection is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work, maybe not the better way but works

```
// Create MongoDB connection
mClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
  global.mongo = db;
  // Start HTTP server  
  server.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("%s listening at %s", server.name, server.url);
  });
});
```